# How to create a connecting line between two asymmetrical shapes in fabric.js?

Tags: fabricjs

**REQUIREMENT**:- Let's take an example we have two triangles or any other shape and I want two connect them with a line - [image]

**PROBLEM**:- I am getting boundingRect coordinates and line is not drawn properly.The line in the below image is drawn from MR control of first object to ML control of second object and not touching the vertex of the shape.[image].

I want to get coordinates of the shape namely (x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3),(x4,y4) in the first image.
Assuming that after fetching these points I can use calculations to find my target points.
Any other solution or ideas will be highly appreciated.

FABRIC VERSION- Fabric 5

```
const fc = new fabric.Canvas("c");

const triangle1Options = {
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 2,
    fill: 'red',
    left: 10,
    top: 10,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
}


let triangle1 = new fabric.Triangle(triangle1Options);

fc.add(triangle1);

// Get coords of triangle
/* The below syntax returns => {
  height: 102,
  left: 10,
  top: 10,
  width: 102
}
This is the bounding rect of triangle. How to get actual coordinates of the triangle. */
fc.on('selection:created', event => {console.log(event.target.getBoundingRect())});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2btqharv/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you connect the line to the center point of each of the objects? And on the stack, put the line behind them, that way it visually looks like it's connecting the strokes:

[image]

I created an example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/fabricjs-connect-line-example-hlco78

If you need to connect specifically at some point on the border, you will need to work with `Polygons` ( http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Polygon.html ), which you can define the points when creating it. And then find the vertices positions relative to canvas. With this, you can evolve to pick the intermediate point between vertices (it would be the origin/end of a connecting line). It's more complex, but achievable. If you choose this path, I write some articles about fabricjs, specifically I've [wrote one](https://medium.com/@luizzappa/how-to-find-out-the-coordinates-of-vertices-of-a-shape-in-fabric-js-a871109085c1) which explains in details how to find the vertices of an object that maybe can help you.